# Replace a specific character at any word's begin and end in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I need to remove the hyphen '-' character only when it matches the pattern 'space-[A-Z]' or '[A-Z]-space'. (Assuming all letters are uppercase, and space could be a space, or newline)

*sample.txt*

```
I AM EMPTY-HANDED AND I- WA-
-ANT SOME COO- COOKIES
```

I want the output to be

```
I AM EMPTY-HANDED AND I WA
ANT SOME COO COOKIES
```

I've looked around for answers using sed and awk and perl, but I could only find answers relating to removing *all* characters between two patterns or specific strings, but not a specific character between [A-Z] and space.

Thanks heaps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> remove the hyphen '-' character only when it matches the pattern 'space-[A-Z]' or '[A-Z]-space'. Assuming all letters are uppercase, and space could be a space, or newline

It's:

```
sed 's/\( \|^\)-\([A-Z]\)/\1\2/g; s/\([A-Z]\)-\( \|$\)/\1\2/g'
```

- `s` - substitute

  - `/`
  - `\( \|^\)` - space or beginning of the line
  - `-` - hyphen...
  - `\(A-Z]\)` - a single upper case character
  - `/`
  - `\1\2` - The `\1` is replaced by the first `\(...\)` thing. So it is replaced by a space or nothing. `\2` is replaced by the single upper case character found. Effectively `-` is removed.
  - `/`
  - `g` apply the regex globally
- `;` - separate two `s` commands
- `s`

  - Same as above. The `$` means end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

If `perl` is your option, would you try the following:

```
perl -pe 's/(^|(?<=\s))-(?=[A-Z])//g; s/(?<=[A-Z])-((?=\s)|$)//g' sample.txt
```

- `(?<=\s)` is a zero-width *lookbehind assertion* which matches leading
  whitespace without including it in the matched substring.
- `(?=[A-Z])` is a zero-width *lookahead assertion* which matches trailing
  character between A and Z without including it in the matched substring.
- As a result, only the dash characters which match the pattern above are
  removed from the original text.
- The second statement `s/..//g` is the flipped version of the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^-[a-zA-Z]+$|^[a-zA-Z]+-$/){sub(/-/,"",$i)}}} 1' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution:

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /^-[a-zA-Z]+$|^[a-zA-Z]+-$/){
      sub(/-/,"",$i)
    }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
I AM EMPTY-HANDED AND I WA
ANT SOME COO COOKIES
```

Comment: It is a good idea to make use of the natural behavior of `awk` to split words on whitespaces to achieve the desired matching pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If you can provide *Extended Regular Expressions* to `sed` (generally with the `-E` or `-r` option), then you can shorten your `sed` expression to:

```
sed -E 's/(^|\s)-(\w)/\1\2/g;s/(\w)-(\s|$)/\1\2/g' file
```

Where the basic form is `sed -E 's/find1/replace1/g;s/find2/replace2/g' file` which can also be written as separate expressions `sed -E -e 's/find1/replace1/g' -e 's/find2/replace2/g'` (your choice).

The details of `s/find1/replace1/g` are:

- `find1` is

  - `(^|\s)` locate and capture at the beginning or whitespace,
  - followed by the `'-'` hyphen,
  - then capture the next `\w` (word-character); and
- `replace1` is simply `\1\2` reinsert both captures with the first two backreferences.

The next substitution expression is similar, except now you are looking for the hyphen followed by a whitespace or at the end. So you have:

- `find2` being

  - a capture of `\w` (word-character),
  - followed by the hyphen,
  - followed by a capture of either a following space or the end `(\s|$)`, then
- `replace2` is the same as before, just reinsert the captured characters using backreferences.

In each case the `g` indicates a global replace of all occurrences.

(**note:** the `\w` word-character also includes the `'_'` (underscore), so while unlikely you would have a hyphen and underscore together, if you do, you need to use the `[A-Za-z]` list instead of `\w`)

**Example Use/Output**

In your case, then output is:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^|\s)-(\w)/\1\2/g;s/(\w)-(\s|$)/\1\2/g' file
I AM EMPTY-HANDED AND I WA
ANT SOME COO COOKIES
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/ -/,"");sub(/^-|-$/,"");sub(/- /," ")}1' file
I AM EMPTY-HANDED AND I WA
ANT SOME COO COOKIES
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/2648551) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!